# Running a process and getting the "Windows protected your PC" message

Tags: c#, process, windows-8.1

I am running this code and I am getting the "Windows protected your PC" message.  Is there a way to tell Windows that this is a safe program and allow it to continue?

The message also states "Windows SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk."

```
private void runProcess(string exeLocation)
{
    var process = Process.Start(exeLocation) // I get error here 
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is built to protect users. Running other "unsigned" programs can be very dangerous for users. Maybe this helps you bit: http://blog.aha-soft.com/windows-smartscreen-prevented-an-unrecognized-app-from-running/

Comment: This question was linked as a duplicate. FYI: link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Your application must have enough "reputation" to not trigger this warning. Here is some more info on how to gain such reputation:

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/DownloadReputation/Default.html?o=1

Also, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16327654/2382032