# Windows SmartScreen prevented an unauthorized app from running

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-8

I developed a c# software using windows 7. IDE is Visual studio 2010 professional, and the only dll it use is `speech.dll`. I generated an installer using the default way `build menu->publish _software name_ -> Finish`, when the setup wizard is on.

I provided the whole `publish` folder into 2 computers, windows 7 and windows 8. App installs fine in both machines but when it is about to run, windows 8 is saying `Windows SmartScreen prevented an unauthorized app from running`

Why is this happening? Please help!

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/6313189/1656796

Comment: @NathanKuchta: tis is now about IE. will it hwlp anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8's SmartScreen is designed to "protect" consumers from malicious programs. In order to be trusted, you need to either buy a cert or sign up to distribute your application through the Windows Store (which costs less money).

It's a terrible move by Microsoft and will hurt devs like you, but there's currently no way around it. You will need to press "More information" when the SmartScreen alert comes up and then press the "Run" button to let your application run.